# Where the JPA query parameter is shipped in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0

a very simple spring repository:

```
public interface OrganizationRepository extends CrudRepository<Organization, Long> {


@Query("select o.name from Organization o where o.name like ?1 ")
List<String> findCompanyName(String term);
```

}

and invoked also simple as:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/names", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<String> getCompanyNameList(@RequestParam String term) {
    List<String> companyNames=organizationRepository.findCompanyName(term);

    return companyNames;
}
```

but in console I get only  SQL like:

```
2012-02-17 23:00:18,105 DEBUG: select organizati0_.name as col_0_0_ from Organization organizati0_ where organizati0_.name like ? >>> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:104)
```

Hibernate: select organizati0_.name as col_0_0_ from Organization organizati0_ where organizati0_.name like ?

where is wrong?

I'm using spring-mvc 3.1.0, Spring-data-jpa 1.1.0,  hibernate-entitymanger 4.0.1 Final

Answer (score 2):

Query looks ok.

If you wish to see the actual parameter values passed to the query, then add following entry to log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

Answer (score 0):

The ? is incorrect.  It should be something like '...where o.name like :name'.